# jQuery Firefox handle behaviour on tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I would like to select an suggestion entry in my input field when I press the TAB key (typical Google behaviour). My Problem is that when I press the TAB key, Firefox sets the focus on the tab in which my application is open, but my concern is that the focus stays on my input field. My code looks something like:

```
$("#search-input").keyup(function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 9:
            {   
                // tab key is pressed
                event.preventDefault();
                foo();
                bar();
                //set focus back to the input (dont works)
                $("#search-input").focus(); 
                break;
            }
        default:
            baz();
    }
});
```

thanks!

[EDIT] Solved! The solution is very easy: Firefox reacts already on `keydown` event so I needed just to put the same behaviour in the keydown event.

Comment: Instead of editing your OP to say you've solved your question, please post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted when the time limit allows you to - this is how you self-solve questions on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Firefox reacts already on keydown event so I needed just to put the same behaviour in the keydown event.

```
$("#search-input").keydown(function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 9:
            {   
                // tab key is pressed
                event.preventDefault();
                foo();
                bar();
                //set focus back to the input (dont works)
                $("#search-input").focus(); 
                break;
            }
        default:
            baz();
    }
});
```